# Getting Undefined variable error when compiling SCSS using node-sass

Tags: css, npm, sass, node-sass

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
  "compile:sass": "node-sass sass/main.scss css/style.css -w"
}
```

**main.scss**

```
@import "abstracts/variables";
@import "base/typography";
```

**_variables.scss**

```
$color-light-grey: #777;
$color-white: #fff;
```

**_typography.scss**

```
body {
  color: $color-light-grey;
}
.heading-primary {
  color: $color-white;
}
```

Now my issue is when I'm trying to compile with `npm run compile:sass` it throws the following error:

> "message": "Undefined variable: \"$color-light-grey\"."

Comment: `variable` vs. `variables`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like there are two errors in your code above:

- You import `"abstracts/variables"` but, at least in the text, the file name seems to be `_variables.scss` (missing an "s")
- You should import `"abstracts/variables"` before everything else.

Like that:

```
@import "abstracts/variables";
@import "base/typography";
```

Comment: It works, but how I don't know. Is there any reason why that would make a difference? Is there needed to order file by priority?

Answer (score 6):

convert all file names with beginning "_"

example: 
**typography.scss** >> to >> **_typography.scss**

Comment: Please ensure that your answer improves upon the answer already present in this question.

Answer (score 0):

Simply import everything in this order

```
 - abstracts
 - vendors
 - base
 - layout
 - components
 - pages
 - themes
```